# Map dataframe function without lambda

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following function:

```
def summarize(text, percentage=.6):
    import numpy as np
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
    sentences = sentences[:int(percentage*len(sentences))]
    summary = ''.join([str(sentence) for sentence in sentences])
    return summary
```

And I want to map it to dataframe rows. It works pretty well when I use the following code :

```
df['summary'] = df['text'].map(summarize)
```

However, when I want to change the percentage variable in this call, it does  `df['summary'] = df['text'].map(summarize(percentage=.8))`, it shows an error indicating it requires another argument, which is `text`. Of course, it can be resolved using a *lambda* function as follows:

```
df['summary'] = df['text'].map(lambda x: summarize(x, percentage=.8))
```

But I do not want use the lambda in the call. Is there any method to do it otherwise? For example using `kwargs` inside the function to refer to the `text` column in the dataframe? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution is use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) instead `map`, then is possible add parameters without lambda like named arguments:

```
df['summary'] = df['text'].map(summarize, percentage=.8)
```

> TypeError: map() got an unexpected keyword argument 'percentage'

---

```
df['summary'] = df['text'].apply(summarize, percentage=.8)
```